# Which file systems use Dokan?

Tags: filesystems, dokan

I've learned about [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/), but I don't know which file systems are implemented using that library.

Is there a list of some file systems that are implemented using Dokan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look here for that the page is down ,but here is wayback link http://web.archive.org/web/20101017115741/http://groups.google.com/group/dokan/web/filesystems-using-dokan? and here are the comments  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dokan/dsnAPLMTNSU/dHIhOdlMMPsJ

Answer (score 2):

**Dokan** has a specific use as described at [dokan-dev.net/en/about/](http://dokan-dev.net/en/about/) page,

> When you want to create a new file system on Windows, for example to improve FAT or NTFS, you need to develop a file system driver. Developing a device driver that works in kernel mode on windows is extremely difficult.
>   By using Dokan library, you can create your own file systems very easily without writing device driver. Dokan Library is similar to FUSE (Linux user mode file system) but works on Windows.

[image]

This UbuntuForums posting on [HOWTO: Share from Linux using sshfs on Windows with "dokan"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1027820) might be useful.